# structure deferencing in C

Tags: c, embedded, structure

```
struct at_response_code
{
    uint8_t *p_string;
    uint8_t event_id;
    uint8_t message_id;
};


struct at_response_code frc_table[] =
{
    (uint8_t*)"OK", EVENT_GSM_ACK_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR,
    (uint8_t*)"+CMS ERROR:", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE, GSM_MSG_ERROR,
    (uint8_t*)"+CME ERROR:", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR,
    (uint8_t*)"ERROR", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR,
    // array terminator !!!
    (uint8_t*) 0, 0, 0
};

static uint8_t parse_command(uint8_t* p_data, struct at_response_code *table, uint8_t* message_id)
{
    struct at_response_code* p_table;
    uint8_t i = 0;
    uint8_t j;
    p_table = &sms_table[0];
    do
    {
       // j = strlen(&(table->p_string));
        j = strlen((char*)&(table[i].p_string));
        if((memcmp_P(table[i]->p_string, p_data, j)) == 0)
        {
            *message_id = table[i]->message_id;
            return table[i]->event_id;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(table[i]->p_string != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here i am always getting a error as dereferencing error,or subscript of pointer to incomplete type when i try to find the length of the string defined in structure using strlen ... can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong, wherever it appears:

```
table[i]-> ...
```

`table` is a pointer to a struct (or an array of structs).  So `table[i]` is a `struct` not a pointer to `struct` so you need the `.` operator to get its members.

**EDIT**

And another thing, I've just noticed your initaliser for `frc_table` is wrong, it needs braces around each struct initialiser

```
struct at_response_code frc_table[] =
{
    { (uint8_t*)"OK", EVENT_GSM_ACK_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR },
    { (uint8_t*)"+CMS ERROR:", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE, GSM_MSG_ERROR },
    { (uint8_t*)"+CME ERROR:", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR },
    { (uint8_t*)"ERROR", EVENT_GSM_ERROR_RESPONSE,GSM_MSG_ERROR },
    // array terminator !!!
    { (uint8_t*) 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `p_string` is a pointer, no need to convert again it to pointer. use following statement

```
j = strlen((table[i]->p_string));
```

Comment: I tried that and i am getting the following error 
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type